# Как изменить регистр i-ой буквы в c++

Tags: c++, xcode

```
string s = "блаблабла";
```

нужно изменить символ s[0] на букву следующего регистра.

```
char ch = s[0];
ch_NullSymbol-='a'-'A';
```

/

```
s[0]-='a'-'A';
```

-- это предлагать не нужно, возникает проблема с русскими символами и кодировкой следовательно.
Есть ли какая-нибудь функция для того чтобы изменить регистр i-ой буквы непосредственно в строке?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого предназначена функция [`toupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/).